# HtmlInputFile through post action

Tags: html

I have a web page which have 3 controls:

1. form using the post command.
2. in the form i have an input file control named "myFile".
3. a button

the upload process works just fine, until I'm trying to post the form and handle the upload in another form.

**Request["myFile"]** and **request.Params["myFile"]** gave me nothing

Answer (score 1):

It's the Request.Files collection you need - look it up in the .NET Framework docs:

```
Request.Files["myFile"]
```

Also make sure that the enctype attribute of your upload form is set correctly - it should be "multipart/form-data" if the form contains file inputs.

Comment: this is not good enough, it gives me a string which represents the address of the file, but i need a HtmlInputFile structure

Comment: No, you don't - read the docs. Request.Files["myFile"] returns an HttpPostedFile object which has all the properties you'll need, and even a SaveAs method to save the file out to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
 <input type="file" size="50" id="ipFile" runat="server"/>
```

`runat="server"` gives you access tot the `HtmlInputFile` structure